# where is php file_put_contents to .txt writing to?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

It's my understanding that you can use PHP to POST values from a form to a .txt file.  I'm attempting to do so in the following code but I have a couple of problems.  For clarity, I'm labeling and commenting my code into a couple sections below for reference.

I have a basic form validation that checks to see if the fields of my form are not empty.  If they aren't empty, it allows the form to 'submit'/POST the form data.  I have included an IF statement that attempts to write the form data to a .txt file if the form is complete, my form validation doesn't seem to work if the fields are empty.  If the fields are full, the code tells me that it wrote data to file.  Upon inspection of the working directory of my XAMPP server however, I cannot find said file.  In fact I can't find it on my computer anywhere.

My questions are this: (1)why does the addition of my IF (labeled with //********THIS IF STATEMENT BELOW IS THE ONE THAT SEEMS TO BREAK MY CODE****) statement to write the form inputs to a text file break my form validation? (2) where is this information being written to?

Thank you for your help and any insight is appreciated.  If you can take the time to explain a little more deeply why something is wrong too then that is also appreciated as this is the first time that i'm attempting this.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
        <h2>MAKE A CLIENT ENTRY</h2>


                            <label for="client">Client:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Client Name" name="client"> *


            <!-- while typing in client, search firm-client database for this client. Once a client is entered, populate any associated matters in the matter input area.  If there is no associated client, offer the option to create new client by dropdown.  Store client name entered in temporary variable. Reveal newClientForm. -->


                            <label for="matter">Matter:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Matter Name" name="matter"> *

            <!--while typing in client-matter, search associated client-matters for an existing matter.  If there is no associated client-matter, offer the option to create a new client-matter by dropdown.  Store client-matter name entere in temporary variable.  Reveal newMatterFrom for client entered-->

                <!--restrict inputs to a date -->

                            <label for="date">Date:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Date" name="date"> *


                        <!--Restrict to double values to the tenth of an hour  -->

                            <label for="time">Time:</label> 
                            <input type="text" placeholder ="Time to nearest tenth hour" name="time"> *



                        <!--no character restrictions  -->
                            <label for="note">Note:</label>
                            <textarea name="note" placeholder ="Enter Any Notes" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> 



                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">     


                        <p class="required">* Required Fields </p>

                        <!-- this is the error div where errors will
                        be displayed.  
                        must figure out why some errors display sometimes and
                        and not all errors

                         -->



<!-- on submit, search firm-client database for this client. if client exists search client-matter database for matter.  if client-matter exists, get matter entries.  add entry to entries. replace client-matter in database  -->
</form>

    <?php
    //form validation for general entry form

    // define variables and set to empty values
    $clientErr = $matterErr = $dateErr = $timeErr = $noteErr= "";
    $client = $matter = $date = $time = $note = "";
    $complete = true;

    //on post, check to see if variable is empty. if not empty
    //parse it and assign value back to variable name

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {



        if (empty($_POST["client"])) {
            $clientErr = "*A client name is required. ";
            $complete = false;
            echo "1";
        }else {


            $client = test_input($_POST["client"]);

        }


        if (empty($_POST["matter"])) {
            $matterErr = "*A matter name is required. ";
            $complete = false;
            echo "2";
        }else {
            $matter = test_input($_POST["matter"]);
        }


        if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
            $dateErr = "*A date is required. ";
            $complete = false;
            echo "3";
        }else {
            $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
        }


        if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
            $timeErr = "*A time entry is required. ";
            $complete = false;
            echo "4";
        }else {
            $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
        }

        if (empty($_POST["note"])) {
            $noteErr = "*A note is required. ";
            $complete = false;
            echo "5";
        } else {
            $note = test_input($_POST["note"]);
        }

        //if $complete is true after all the if satements above run then
        //append each entry together with a '-' separating the data and with
        // '\n' at the end.
        if ($complete){
            //appending of the input data
            $data = $_POST["client"].'-'.$_POST["matter"].'-'.$_POST["date"].'-'.$_POST["time"].'-'.$_POST["note"]."\n";
            //create the mydata.txt file in the current directory with the 
            //value of $data.  If the file exists already, appened to it
            //with the value of $data.
            $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            //if $ret and false are identical (same value and type)
            //then output that there was an error writing the file.
            //else echo that the bytes were written to the file.
            if($ret === false) {
                 die('There was an error writing this file');
                }
            else {
                echo "$ret bytes written to file";
            }
        }

        else {
            die('no post data to process');

        }


    } 

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
?>



<div class="errorDiv">

    <?php 
    echo $clientErr;
    echo $matterErr; 
    echo $dateErr;
    echo $timeErr; 
    echo $noteErr;
    ?>      

</div>

<div class="inputDisplay">

    <?php
    //have to change this to an array to display the input correctly and not
    //just the last of the inputs submitted
        echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
        echo $client;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $matter;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $date;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $time;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $note;


    ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably by removing the irrelevant html? Also you could make some note in the code at "addition of my IF statement", as it's not clear which one you mean

Comment: I will endeavor to do so but 3 lines of html showing the grid structure would not in my opinion be so onerous as to require cutting out.  Unless you're saying there's more.  In that case, i'm just not well versed enough in HTML to know what other code is superfluous.  With respect to the IF statement, I can see how that needs clarifying.  I'm going to try to label it in red and thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Does the tmp directory exist / do you have permissions? Try  `$ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`
 and see if it shows.

Comment: 2/3 of your posted code seems to be irrelevant, especially the 1st "page", not many will scroll down

Comment: @Matt the tmp directory does exist.  I believe I have permission to write to it as I unlocked the folder to allow all read/write permissions in OS X. When i fill in all the data to my form as is, it also gives me that it xxx"bytes written to file."

Comment: @Gavriel then I don't know enough about html to know what's irrelevant because my understanding is I need all the code above except for column and row code.  If you would like to expound I would like to know.

Comment: @Matt when I tried to use your suggestion above i received the following error "Warning: file_put_contents(mydata.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/backup/1.28.16/index.php on line 131
There was an error writing this file"


when I try to do it to the directory I specified, I get no such error and only the xxx"bytes written to file."

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" > Correct this if you use "" outside then you need to use ' ' inside or viceversa

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos on OSX the `tmp` directory exists! Try it `cd /tmp` in Terminal. Otherwise, through `echo $TMPDIR` (in Terminal).

Comment: @fusion3k wow... thank you. It was my understanding that the way I had the code written it would write to the working directory of the .php page not the working directory of the user.  I found it using what you suggested and this now answers my question.  Is there a way to direct the writing of the file to the working directory of the .php file that contains my code or is it only by writing the full path of that directory?

Comment: I don't known XAMPP. Try with `file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/YourFileName.txt")`, but directory must be writable by Apache/XAMPP or all users

Comment: @fusion3k am I substitute the dirname for the directory name? or __FILE__ for the directory name. I'm assuming __FILE__.  I did make the directory writeable by all users so hopefully that won't be an issue.

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos No, you have to change only your filename (keep the slash!). `dirname(__FILE__)` is a command that outputs full directory path of current file working. see [dirname](http://www.php.net/dirname) and [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 0):

In every place you have `$complete = false;`, add `echo "1";` with a different number in each place. Now try again, and you'll see which previous condition causes $complete to become false.

Or if you want to see te errors in the div delete these 3 lines:

```
    else {
        die('no post data to process');

    }
```

Comment: interesting @gavriel , why does echo work here but not in the php statements below where I attempt to report the errors in the "errorDiv".  Is it because the page doesn't get to read that far once it realizes that the form cannot be submitted?  It's odd because if I comment out the last IF statement that I referenced above, the posting of the errors to the "errorDiv" appears to work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity with the above edit above as to why the items don't post to my errorDiv. It make a lot more sense when you point out this line of code explicitly.  Any clue as to my first question re: where this is actually being written since I have the directory /tmp but no .txt file seems to write in there with data even after my code returns that xx"bytes were written to file."

Comment: Do ypou see 'There was an error writing this file' or X 'bytes written to file'?

Comment: If I change the directory to one without r w permission I do but for this one it gives me no error.  It only tells me "10 bytes written to file." Or whatever bite size it is based on how much data I try to write.

Comment: so at least 10 bytes must be in /tmp/mydata.txt

Comment: To troubleshoot I've tried to two things. 1. add a .txt file named "mydata.txt" to the directory. But nothing will write to that and it remains 1 byte big.  2. Leave the folder blank and see if it will create it.  It does not.

Comment: It's probaby exactly the cause of the problem. You probably created that file as user, and php wants to write to it as www-data or apache. Try deleting the file before you test.